# flutter to enable and disable various Check_List_Tile using one boolean variable

Tags: dart, flutter

I am new to flutter. in my project, there is a various `check_list_tile` depending upon the length of the List (attendance list). And I have used one Boolean variable. Now when I press on one checkbox it automatically checks all other checkboxes. Please help me in this (on tap one checkbox should not change the state of all other checkboxes except clicked). I have copied all code please check `check_box_list` field.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'dart:async';
Map map_student_data;
Iterable iter_student_data,iter_student_key;
List list_student_data,list_student_key;
 bool t=true,checkbox=false;
  List list;
  String validation="yes";
int i;
int year;
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;

class IImca_attendence extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _IImca_attendenceState createState() => _IImca_attendenceState();
}




class _IImca_attendenceState extends State<IImca_attendence> {

  @override
void initState(){
  this.check_year();
  super.initState();


}

  DateTime date = DateTime.now();    
Future check_year()async{
  var k= await database.reference().child("NITTE/CLASS/MCA").once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot){


      Map sea=  snapshot.value;
      Iterable iter=sea.keys;
     list=iter.toList();
      list.sublist(list.length-1);
       list.sort();
       setState(() {
          year=list.length-2;       
              });
       check();
  });
}

Future check()async{
   var m=await database.reference().child("NITTE/CLASS/MCA/${list[year].toString().toUpperCase()}/STUDENT").once().then((DataSnapshot currentyear){
            map_student_data=currentyear.value;
            iter_student_data=map_student_data.values;
            iter_student_key=map_student_data.keys;
            list_student_data=iter_student_data.toList();
            list_student_key=iter_student_key.toList();
            for(i=0;i<=list_student_data.length;i++){
               bool ss=true;
            }

           });

}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("II-MCA"),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.refresh),onPressed: (){
            setState(() {
                  check_year();

                        });
           })
        ],
      ),

      body: 
  validation=="1"?
   new Center(
        child: Text("STUDENT DOSE NOT EXIST IN $year",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 20),),

     ):
    new ListView.builder(
      itemCount: list_student_data==null?0
      :list_student_data.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){
        var student_detail= ['NAME : ${list_student_data[index]['NAME']}','GENDER : ${list_student_data[index]['CURRENT CLASS']}','PHOTO : ${list_student_data[index]['PHOTO']}'];
        return new Container(
          child: new Center(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Card(
                  child: new Container(
                    child: CheckboxListTile(
                      title: Text("${list_student_key[index]}",style:TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),), 
                      subtitle: Text("NAME : ${list_student_data[index]['NAME']}"),
                      value: checkbox,
                      onChanged: (val){
                        setState(() {
                               checkbox=val;  
                               if(checkbox==true){
                                 print("${list_student_data[index]['NAME']}: i am absent");
                               }if(checkbox==false){
                                 print("${list_student_data[index]['NAME']}: i am present");
                               }

                                                });

                      },

                    ),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
  )

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Everyone would appreciate if you would auto-format your code before posting it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well... you are using a **global** `checkbox` variable, so It's quite normal that if you change it, all widget depending on its state will change accordingly.

What I suggest you to do is to add the `selected` state inside your model class. Just as an example, assumed you have this Student class (I know you are using firebase, but for sake of time I don't)

```
class Student {
  var name = 'foo';
  var year = '2018';
  var selected = false;

  Student(this.name);
}
```

This class has is `selected` state inside of it.

Now assume that your snapshot give you 3 students. Always for sake of time I've embedded a local array:

```
class _IImca_attendenceState extends State<IImca_attendence> {
  var _students = [Student('foo'), Student('pub'), Student('beer')];
  ...
```

(Ellipses are not part of code... ;-])

I suggest you to put your state variables inside the Stateful Widget scope and not onto the Global Scope.

That said you could have:

```
ListView.builder(
    itemCount: _students.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return new Container(
        child: new Center(
            child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
                new Card(
                child: new Container(
                    child: CheckboxListTile(
                    title: Text(
                        _students[index].name,
                        style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                    ),
                    subtitle:
                        Text("NAME : ${_students[index].name}"),
                    value: _students[index].selected,
                    onChanged: (val) {
                        setState(() {
                        _students[index].selected = val;
                        if (!_students[index].selected) {
                            print(
                                '${_students[index].name}: i am absent');
                        }
                        if (_students[index].selected) {
                            print(
                                '${_students[index].name}: i am present');
                        }
                        });
                    },
                    ),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                ),
                )
            ],
            ),
        ),
        );
    }
)
```

You should also use an array of bool(s) of the same length of your snapshot data students array... but I'd like to suggest to track this information directly on your `Student` model.

[image]

**UPDATE**

As you are more comfortable using array I've change my code using a complementary `array of bool` of the same size of your student list.

All you have to do is an array (not a single value) of boolean values, the same size of your student array, lets call this `list_student_present` (I instead use `list_student_present2`)

At the beginning you initialize this in your `check function` a way like that:

```
list_student_data = iter_student_data.toList();
// This is the array you wanna use (first all false)
list_student_present = iter_student_data.map((_) => false).toList();
```

And then you will use this array of bool to check the state of your checkboxes:

```
itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return new Container(
                child: new Center(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Card(
                        child: new Container(
                          child: CheckboxListTile(
                            title: Text(
                              _students[index].name,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                            subtitle:
                                Text("NAME : ${_students[index].name}"),
                            value: list_student_present[index],
                            onChanged: (val) {
                              setState(() {
                                list_student_present[index] = val;
                                if (!list_student_present[index]) {
                                  print(
                                      '${_students[index].name}: i am absent');
                                }
                                if (list_student_present[index]) {
                                  print(
                                      '${_students[index].name}: i am present');
                                }
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
```

Do not use my Student class (I continue using it so that I'm able to show you data without firebase), continue using your students array list from your firebase snapshot.

**Full code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

Map map_student_data;
Iterable iter_student_data, iter_student_key;
List list_student_data, list_student_key, list_student_present, list_student_present2;
bool t = true;
List list;
String validation = "yes";
int i;
int year;

class Student {
  var name = 'foo';
  var year = '2018';
  var selected = false;

  Student(this.name);
}

class IImca_attendence extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _IImca_attendenceState createState() => _IImca_attendenceState();
}

class _IImca_attendenceState extends State<IImca_attendence> {
  var _students = [Student('foo'), Student('pub'), Student('beer')];
  @override
  void initState() {
    this.check_year();
    super.initState();
  }

  DateTime date = DateTime.now();
  Future check_year() async {
    Map sea = {1: 'atlantic', 2: 'pacific'};
    Iterable iter = sea.keys;
    list = iter.toList();
    list.sublist(list.length - 1);
    list.sort();
    setState(() {
      year = list.length - 2;
    });
    check();
  }

  Future check() async {
    map_student_data = {
      0: {'NAME': 'foo', 'CURRENT CLASS': 'pub', 'PHOTO': ''}
    };
    iter_student_data = map_student_data.values;
    iter_student_key = map_student_data.keys;
    list_student_data = iter_student_data.toList();
    // This is the array you wanna use
    list_student_present = iter_student_data.map((_) => false).toList();
    // This is the array for my example
    list_student_present2 = _students.map((_) => false).toList();
    list_student_key = iter_student_key.toList();
    for (i = 0; i <= list_student_data.length; i++) {
      bool ss = true;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("II-MCA"),
          centerTitle: true,
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.refresh),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    check_year();
                  });
                })
          ],
        ),
        body: validation == "1"
            ? new Center(
                child: Text(
                  "STUDENT DOSE NOT EXIST IN $year",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 20),
                ),
              )
            : ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _students.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return new Container(
                    child: new Center(
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Card(
                            child: new Container(
                              child: CheckboxListTile(
                                title: Text(
                                  _students[index].name,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                subtitle:
                                    Text("NAME : ${_students[index].name}"),
                                value: list_student_present2[index],
                                onChanged: (val) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    list_student_present2[index] = val;
                                    if (!list_student_present2[index]) {
                                      print(
                                          '${_students[index].name}: i am absent');
                                    }
                                    if (list_student_present2[index]) {
                                      print(
                                          '${_students[index].name}: i am present');
                                    }
                                  });
                                },
                              ),
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }));
  }
}
```

I really don't like this solution. What I suggest you is to create your PODOs (Plain Old Dart Object) representing your firebase models and deserialise them from your firebase snapshots.

Comment: I have tested your code it is working well. but my problem is still not yet solved. U have used a class named student can you eliminate that class I didn't understand that I am trying to retrieve firebase data it will be in the form of Map and I am converting to list. to use that inlistviewbuilder. and if i use that list[which contains key or data received from forebase][index ] .boolen_variable then i am receiving an error :=> (I/flutter (32413): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'String' has no instance getter 'checkbox'.)

Comment: variable to the checkboxlistTile value. please try to help me i have stuck there.thank
so please help me in this .and instead of class use direct list or map thank you for your help.

Comment: @YogishShenoy I've update my answer following your "arrays" approach even if I don't like the solution. C'ya.

Comment: No i liked but i dono how to implement in my project it is showing error...

Comment: @YogishShenoy look if the array approach is working. Than use it. If it works you cann accept my answer. Then you could make a new one asking for that (remember to post also your JSON firebase data). In the meanwhile I left you with some interesting material to study [1](https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data), [2](https://flutter.io/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#serializing-json-using-code-generation-libraries), [3](https://github.com/flutter/samples/tree/master/jsonexample)